# Integrating Cortana with Different languages

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

I am creating an app in which I have integrated Cortana. Its in English version and all is working fine. Now I would like to add one more language(er.French or Italian) I know that I have to add one more commandset with xml:lang tag. But how can I test it? Do I needs to change the phone language also? or with my current English language will work for different language? Please help

Comment: I did not test this, but I believe you have to change the language of the test phone you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the language of the phone is an option, but you can also simply add additional language "packs" to your phone. Go to Settings -> Speech and then open the Speech languages list. You'll see all the supported languages on Windows Phone, along with a download size, which indicates they are not yet installed. Select the language to download and then wait. Installing a new language pack is considered a system update, which means it'll have to reboot the phone and perform the long data migration process. Your phone will be unusable for 20-30 minutes or more. repeat for more languages.

Once a language is installed, you can use Cortana VCD, text-to-speech and speech recognition in your apps in that language.

You can also use the Windows Phone emulator since the images come pre-loaded with all the languages by default. This is a great way to test all the possible languages for an international deployment (provided you are familiar with said languages).

To learn more about speech & Cortana integration in Windows & WP apps, let me recommend this free online course on Microsoft Virtual Academy: http://aka.ms/cortanamva.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick! I created voice application in two languages and its working! BTW I saw the online course in MVA and your presentation really helped me a lot. Hope more videos from you in these areas :) Many thanks Nick